# Could not locate assembly

Tags: sharepoint, key, web-parts, token, public

I have a SharePoint webpart for which I have had to change its public key.  However, I don't appear to be able to locate every reference to the old assembly signed with this key.

Now I get a 'Parser Error'...

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly '[Assembly.name], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[Old public key token]' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anyone advise me how I can trace what is referencing this assembly?  I've deleted the instance of the web part on the page that is causing this error - what more can I do?

Thanks in advance,

Flippsie

Answer (score 0):

Each webpart instance references the DLL explicitly. You can verify this by exporting the webpart and then opening up the file in a text editor. You'll see your DLL called out between the `<Assembly></Assembly>` node.

Try adding the webpart back to the page again. You may have to make a new DWP/.WEBPART file or update it in the Webpart gallery.

Comment: I have completely removed the old solution and reinstalled the new version.  I have to put the old assembly back in the bin folder to be able to remove the old web part from the page, but when I return the new assembly to the bin and try to add the web part again, I still get this Parser Error and it's using the old public key still!

If I export the we part it clearly references the assembly using the new public key.

Where has it squirrelled away this seemingly undeletable old public key?

Comment: Well, it probably depends on how you deployed the web part... but I'm guessing the old one is still in the web part gallery. Are you using SharePoint 2007 or SharePoint 2010?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2007, sorry, should have stated that to begin with.

Comment: So although there were no visible entries in the web part gallery, there were three entries in the wpcatalog, in the content database for the web part that is causing me a problem.  Even with these entries removed, I still get this parser error! A page directive trying to reference the web part assembly by it's old PublicKeyToken.

Comment: Page directive? Did you add the web part in a master page or something?

Comment: No, there is only one master page for the whole site and there are no instances of the web part within it.

Comment: I've gotten around this issue by recreating my web part under a new name, as the alternative of recreating all the pages was too labour intensive.  However, this does mean that I must always leave this spurious assembly in the bin, to prevent an exception being thrown.  Far from ideal, so if anyone has any other ideas about why this is happening......?

Comment: Is it the SafeControl entry in the web.config? How did you deploy the web part?

Comment: There is no longer a SafeControl entry in the web.config.  The solution has been retracted and removed.  There are no instances of the web part on any page within my site.  If there were I would be able to locate them in the content database.  Would not a SafeControl entry be superfluous?

Comment: Yeah it would no longer be needed but it might throw an error if it was still listed in the web.config. I was just thinking of places the web part could still be referenced.

Comment: Idea.. when you say you "deleted the web part".. did you click the X or did you click Edit -> Delete. Perhaps the webpart is still on the page but closed? You can use the contents=1 URL parameter to list all the web parts on the page.

Comment: No, I really do mean that instnces of the web part have been deleted.  There are none that are just closed.  These would still show up in the Content Database.